# VIM: Spaces disappeared after using retab

Tags: linux, vim

I ran `:retab` in VIM, and I can no longer see spaces before any characters.

The following lines are in my .vimrc:

```
" white space symbols when list enabled
set listchars=eol:¬,tab:▸-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
```

After retab, I expected to see

```
~~~~My~line¬
```

but instead i get

```
My line¬
```

However if the line was just a tab then it looks like this:

```
~~~~¬
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: You should set your space to a symbol to be able to see those in *list mode*, *trail*s are just *trailing spaces* at the end of lines: do `set listchars+=space:~` or add `,space:~` at the end of your existing `set listchars` in *.vimrc*

Comment: `space:~ ` isn't accepted by my vim. Using version 7.3